# Use CSS bottom property the opposite way, possible?

Tags: html, css

Got a question here. I'm trying to make a little contact information div at the bottom of the page. When I click a link it should slide up. The JS is no problem here, but I'm struggling with the position of the div.

The div has got a variable height, but must have a bottom:-x; value, where the x is variable as well.

If the bottom:; property would work the opposite way, so that value 0 would make the div's top stick to the bottom, it wouldn't be a problem.

Difficult to explain. Maybe just have a look at the code in jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="link">Contact</div>
    <div class="info">
        <ul>
            <li>Name, Middle Name, Surname</li>
            <li>Street, number</li>
            <li>Zip, City</li>
            <li>Variable height div</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.box{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: -.1em;
    right: 2em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.link{
    height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #268963;
}

.info{
    border: .1em solid #268963;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBd2V/1/

Comment: What is the problem? Setting `bottom:0` will place the bottom of the element at the bottom of the parent. If it would be the oposite you would have a problem, because then the element would be outside the parent, in this case outside the window.

Comment: I wanted it outside the window, but got my answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting a `top` style of `100%`, and then applying a negative `margin-top` for any movements back up you want to make. In your case, you'd need the following:

```
.box{
    position:fixed;
    top: 100%;
    right: 2em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBd2V/2/)

Then you can toggle between what you had and this code to toggle the menu. The only problem then would be that you can't transition between the two, since you'd be alternating between `top:100%;` and `top:auto;`, and `bottom:0;` and `bottom:auto;`, if you want to toggle it.

Comment: Pff why didn't I come up with this.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just going to use it over the full height, then it works, tx!

Comment: @PepijnGieles what exactly are you trying to achieve? the green flag has to stick out the bottom and then when clicked the whole box should slide up/down? why do you need the box to have its top on page bottom? just to hide it? can't you use jQuery .hide() to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the .box's 'bottom' property to '0', and play with the .info's height.
I edited the fiddle a bit, you can see how it works if you add/remove the class 'open' to the .box element:

```
.box{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 2em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.info{
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    height:0px;
}
.box.open .info {
    height:auto;
    border: .1em solid #268963;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBd2V/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you want to achieve, but you should just add a little jQuery to your code and it works fine like this :

```
$('.info').hide()
$('.link').click(function(){

    $('.info').slideToggle()

})
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBd2V/3/)